# Hive query with Group By : Failed to parse

Tags: sql, hive

We are trying to run a hive query using hivecontext(1.6.0) but getting a 'AnalysisException'. The query is as follows :

```
 select  coalesce( an, dan),  case when  coalesce( ts, dts) is null then null else ( add_seconds( to_timestamp( concat( to_char( sub_seconds(  coalesce( ts, dts),81368), 'yyyyMMdd'), '000000'), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'), 81368) ) end,  sum( case when ( mmm in (  1 ) and mgk is null ) then 1 else 0 end ),  sum( case when ( mmm in (  2 ) and mgk is null ) then 1 else 0 end ),  sum( case when ( mmm = 3 and dco_ids is not null ) then 1 else 0 end ),  sum( case when ( mmm = 3 and dco_ids is null and mgk is null ) then 1 else 0 end ),  sum( case when ( mgk is not null ) then 1 else 0 end ) from mrdm group by  coalesce( an, dan),  case when  coalesce( ts, dts) is null then null else ( add_seconds( to_timestamp( concat( to_char( sub_seconds(  coalesce( ts, dts),81368), 'yyyyMMdd'), '000000'), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'), 81368) ) end
```

The error against the query from hive is :

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression 'ts' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:44)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like an Hive code (add_seconds,sub_seconds,to_char,to_timestamp). Where did you take this code from?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I have not "taken" this code from anywhere. This query is (our)code generated and add_seconds ,sub_seconds ,to_char and to_timestamp are our custom UDFs.

Comment: If the parser is not 100% sure that your UDFs are **deterministic**, then it has a good reason to refuse using them in a GROUP BY clause. Why don't you wrap all your UDFs and `colaesce` in a sub-query, then GROUP BY on the result?

Comment: where's the rest of the query? I just see the select. The issue is likely that you're selecting a column that's not in your `group by` so hive doesn't know which `ts` from the group to use since there may be multiple values

Comment: @FuzzyTree you can scroll and check the query. I totally understand this part, but according to the query, the select and group by predicates are in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a derived table so you don't have to redefine your `case` statement:

```
select 
    c1, c2,
    sum(.....),
    sum(.....)
from (
    select *,
        coalesce(an, dan) c1,
        case when ... end c2           
    from mrdm 
) t group by c1, c2
```